# Generating edit link when clicking a row

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am trying to generate a link to an update/edit link to edit the contact details.
It won't work, when clicking on a row I get a "Link not found" error.
This is the row link code I am trying to initiate on click:

```
<tr class="row100 body clickable" href="{{ url_for('main.update_noc', row_id=data.row_id) }}">
```

I have a piece of python code which gets the data from sqlite3 which looks like this:

```
def get_noc(row_id):
data = get_db().execute(
    'SELECT p.id, contact, company, p.email, phone, datacenter,row_id'
    ' FROM noc p JOIN users u ON p.row_id',
).fetchone()

if data is None:
    abort (404, "Data does not exist!". format(row_id))

return data
```

The update function looks like this:

```
@bp.route('/noc/<int:row_id>/update', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@login_required
def update_noc(row_id):
    data = get_noc(row_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        contact = request.form['contact']
        company = request.form['company']
        email = request.form['email']
        phone = request.form['phone']
        datacenter = request.form['datacenter']
        error = None

        if company is None:
            error = 'Company is required.'
        elif contact is None:
            error = 'Contact is required.'
        elif phone is None:
            error = 'Phone number is required.'
        elif email is None:
            error = 'Email is required.'

        if error is not None:
            flash(error)
        else:
            db = get_db()
            db.execute(
                'UPDATE noc SET contact = ?, company = ?, email = ?, phone = ?, datacenter = ?, row_id = ?'
                ' WHERE id = ?',
                (contact, company, email, phone, datacenter, row_id)
            )
            db.commit()
            return redirect (url_for('main.noc'))
    return render_template('main/update_noc.html',data=data)
```

I got through the flask tutorial from the documentation and used the knowledge I got there. It still won't work but when I manually go to `/noc/1/update` the page works normally...

I tried changing variables and played a lot with the sql, without any success...
I suspect I did something wrong in my jinja2 code... Or in the `return render_template('main/update_noc.html',data=data)`

This is the sql table which initiates this pasrt of my app:

```
CREATE TABLE noc (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
contact TEXT NOT NULL,
company TEXT NOT NULL,
email TEXT NOT NULL,
phone INTEGER NOT NULL,
datacenter TEXT NOT NULL,
row_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (row_id) REFERENCES noc (id)
);
```

Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your example code is great but could you also include the actual error please? Where does it say "link not found"?

Comment: In the browser after clicking the row a 404 error picks up:
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Comment: `'SELECT p.id, contact, company, p.email, phone, datacenter,row_id' ' FROM noc p JOIN users u ON p.row_id'` doesn't make sense because you're not passing `row_id` to the query. I'm not sure why you have a join here

Comment: Other than that query, which doesn't add up to me (and we'd be going down a rabbit hole I think with then looking at schema), everything else seems fine to me

Comment: Alright, I got rid of that, it did not fix the problem.

Could it be something in my javascript code? It should not matter as the javascript only makes the row clickable...

Comment: At least on chrome, you can right click somewhere on the page and use "view page source". You'll be able to see there whether the link was correctly rendered by jinja. As for the JS aspect, no idea sorry because we can't see that. At this stage, I think the scope is too broad but check the rendering first

Comment: SQLite will not automatically return a dictionary for results in a query row. We can't see the DB config but `row_id=data.row_id` isn't going to work out-of-the-box unless you've configured the query to return dicts. Instead, you'll need to access by index, not key

Comment: When going by index it didn't work at all. The weirdest part is that when I manually type the link in, it goes to the corresponding update page normally.

I sill suspect there is something goind wrong with the js script...
`jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $(".clickable").click(function() {
          window.location = $(this).data("href");
      });
  });`

In the view element it seems to return this function no matter what:
`function(b) {
  return "undefined" != typeof r && r.event.triggered !== b.type ? r.event.dispatch.apply(a, arguments) : void 0
}`

Comment: I don't see why any of that is necessary since the button should happily send a GET request without anything on the front-end. At this point, though, you'll see that this question is getting too broad to be debugged here because we can't pin it down with what you've given. You'll need to isolate the issue more closely yourself beforehand

Comment: I tried to isolate it but can't get anywhere... I have added my sql schema to the question. Maybe that helps? 

I troubleshooted a lot! I have been trying to fix this since friday... It bugs me down.

Comment: The SQL schema won't help because it's either going to return data or not. And I genuinely have tried to help you pin it down but you can see we're not moving forward. It's not that I don't want to help, it's that I (and I suspect others) won't be able to here. I wish you luck, stick at it

Comment: One approach would be to build up a [mcve] from scratch using new routes. That way, you can sequentially test the output at each stage of building it up, rather than looking at a complete product and going backwards to find the problem

Comment: I have an idea what could be a solution. In the sql schema I reference the primary key id with the row_id but I already increment the row_id whith 1 when I create a new contact. Maybe that sets off the database. I will try it out when I am home.

Comment: I fixed the first problem and added the answer to this post. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by changing the javascript code which makes the row clickable from:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".clickable").click(function() {
        window.location = $(this).data("href");
    });
});
```

to:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $('[data-href]').click(function () {
                window.location = $(this).data("href");
            })
        });
```

With that I changed the jinja2 code to:

```
<tr class="row100 body" data-href="{{ url_for('main.update_noc', row_id=data.row_id) }}">
```

The javascript stops using a class and uses the data-href directly.

This works perfectly now!

Thanks for all the insight!